Area of the parallelogram formed by joining the midpoints of the sides of a quadrilateral

$E, G, F$ and $H$ are the mid-points of the sides of the quadrilateral $ABCD$. Prove that the area of $EGFH$ is half of the area of $ABCD$.


Since the sides of $EGFH$ are parallel to the diagonal of the original quadrilateral, we can deduce that $EGFH$ is a parallelogram. I could solve this problem as follows:
We have $S_{\triangle BEG}= \frac14 S_{\triangle ABC}$ and $S_{\triangle DFH}= \frac14 S_{\triangle ADC}$. Hence $S_{\triangle BEG} + S_{\triangle DFH}= \frac14 S_{ABCD}$. Similarly, $S_{\triangle CFG} + S_{\triangle AEH}= \frac14 S_{ABCD}$. Hence, $S_{EGFH}= \frac12 S_{ABCD}$.
However, I'm interested to see other approaches for solving this problem.

Another approach is to identify the intersection point of the two diagonals ($I$ on my diagram) and then observe that $S_{\triangle AEH} = S_{\triangle IEH}$ and so on.
To convince yourself that the areas of the triangles truly are the same, observe that they share a base and it can be easily verified they have the same height (one way would be to drop a perpendicular from $A$ to $DB$ and confirm that $HE$ bisects it).


I'm afraid there is not a lot space for improvisation here. I suppose every proof of this fact will eventually end up chasing the middlesegment argument or more generally Thales's interception theorem. For example @Adam-Dougall's one refers to one of them eventually.
Another way to say more or less the same is to notice that
$$
S_{ABCD} = \frac{AC\cdot BD\cdot \sin(\alpha)}{2}
$$
(here $\alpha$ is the angle between $AC$ and $BD$). But $HE = BD/2$ and $HE\parallel BD$ as a middlesegment. Likewise $HF = AC/2$ and $HF\parallel AC$. Thus angle between $HE$ and $HF$ is also $\alpha$ and
$$
S_{HEGF} = HE\cdot HF\cdot\sin(\alpha) = \frac{BD}{2}\cdot\frac{AC}{2}\cdot\sin(\alpha) = \frac{S_{ABCD}}{2}
$$

I think this is pretty accurate. OP’s proof is so elementary already it’s hard for any other proof to be substantially different without being artificially and unnecessarily complicated.

@Adam-Dougall Indeed!
